# Colorbuffer does not work properly while applied on a circle

Tags: android, opengl-es

When i was applying color buffer and blending on a solid circle, the color in first 20 degrees does not display properly, I got some sort of color ribbon but that is not what it supposed to be, maybe I have done something wrong in my code?

```
public class Circle {
boolean circleChecked;
 private int points=361;
    private float vertices[]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    private float[] fogcolor = {0.2f,0.4f,0.7f,0.9f};
    private FloatBuffer vertBuff, textureBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;   // Buffer for color-array (NEW)
    float texData[] = null;
    private float[] colors = { // Colors for the vertices (NEW)
              0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,0.5f,
              0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,0.5f,
              0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,0.5f
           };

    float theta = 0;
    int[] textures = new int[1];
    int R=1;
    float textCoordArray[] = 
        {
            -R, 
            (float) (R * (Math.sqrt(2) + 1)),
             -R, 
             -R,
            (float) (R * (Math.sqrt(2) + 1)), 
            -R
        };
    public Circle(float size, float positionX, float positionY){

        vertices = new float[(points)*3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i+=3){
            vertices[i]=positionX * size;
            vertices[i+1]=positionY *size;
            vertices[i+2]=0.51f;
        }
        for(int i=3;i<(points)*3;i+=3)
        {       

                vertices[i]=((float) ( Math.cos(theta))/3+positionX) * size;
                vertices[i+1]=((float) (Math.sin(theta))/3+positionY) *size;
                vertices[i+2]=0.5f;
                theta += Math.PI / 90;

        }
        ByteBuffer bBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);    
          bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
          vertBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
          vertBuff.put(vertices);
          vertBuff.position(0);

          // Setup color-array buffer. Colors in float. A float has 4 bytes (NEW)
          ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
          cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order (NEW)
          colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();  // Convert byte buffer to float (NEW)
          colorBuffer.put(colors);            // Copy data into buffer (NEW)
          colorBuffer.position(0);            // Rewind (NEW)

        ByteBuffer bBuff2=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textCoordArray.length * 4 *       360);
        bBuff2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer=bBuff2.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(textCoordArray);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl){ 
    //gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    //gl.glColor4f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer); 
   // if(circleChecked){
    //  gl.glColor4f(0.2f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 1);
    //}
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glPushMatrix(); 
    gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_MODE, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_START, 3.0f);
    gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_END, 5.0f);
    float fogColor[] = {1f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
    gl.glFogfv(GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor, 0);
    gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.9f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_FOG);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //4
    //gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, textureBuffer); //5
       // gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);   // Disable color-array (NEW)
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    //gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_FOG);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your color array. glDrawArrays `gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);` will take values from each buffer you enable its client state "gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)". The number of those values equals to the last parameter and in your case `points/2` but your color buffer has only 3 values. The result is that only first of your triangles has correct color mapping, all the rest is garbage and the results are unpredictable.

Although this might seem inefficient for your case, you will need to repeat those color parameters in your "for" loop where you set your vertex coordinates and the length of the buffer should be the same as "vertBuffer". And by length I mean number of values, not bytes, where 1 color value consists of 4 float values and 1 position value consists of 3 float values in your case.

Comment: I did the colorbuffer like what you said, and it is perfect. Many thanks!